# Entity framework - how long should it take to add 75k rows?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a following setup:

- Table1 - 150k rows currently, need to add another 25k rows,
- Table2 - 300k rows, need to add another 50k.

I add rows in a loop, like that (EF code first):

```
using (var context = new MyDb())
{
  loop() //25k rounds
  {
    var t3 = new Table2();
    var t2 = new Table2();
    var t1 = new Table1{prop1 = t2, prop2 = t3};
    context.Table1.Add(t1);
    context.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

So, the loop will take 25k turns in total, and my performance measurement shows me, that it will add those rows in roughly **ten hours**! And now I have no idea if it is because this is a normal time for this kind of operation with EF, or because there is something wrong with my dbms?

Comment: Is this a one time thing? If so EF probably isn't the best choice here. But I'm going to vote to close because how long something like this takes is based on a lot of factors, such as the database type/size/design/whether the tables are indexed etc, I think too many to give any sort of a useful answer.

Comment: I'd guess that you shouldn't `SaveChanges` every single time. Maybe do it in 1k chunks?

Comment: Move `SaveChanges` outside loop?

Comment: @JMK: What else could I use? SQL is not the option here due to the complexity of the problem (I obviously shortened it alot in the above example)

Comment: I'm not sure if it would be much simpler to generate that SQL statements and fire them directly to a sql interpreter. You also did not tell us if the db is in productive usage or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this answer to a similar question

[Fastest Way of Inserting in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework)

The problem is that everytime you go round the loop you are saving the changes to the DB, this results in 25k db writes rather than just one

Comment: I didn't look at it this way, that will surely help, thanks!

Comment: You should include a summary, quote, relevant code, or example of his code modified to implement this. Not just a link and the short summary you've got.

Answer (score 3):

EF is not designed for efficient bulk update/insert.  I would recommend using another method like `BCP` (command-line utility to import from text files),  `SqlBulkCopy` form C# (which is basically a .NET wrapper for BCP, or an ETL tool like SSIS.

If you are *generating* the data in your program (not copying it form another locaiton) then you might try building an `INSERT` SQL command and using `SqlCommand`.